# filepath of children

Tags: php, oop, design-patterns

`class a1 extends class b{}
class a2 extends class b{}
class a3 extends class b{}
class a4 extends class b{}
class a5 extends class b{}`

I need $this->filePath in each a1 to a5 that point to location of it's file, but when I set $this->filePath = __FILE__ in parent, in children $this->filePath point to parent location

Comment: what is the visiblity of property filepath?

Comment: Typically \_\_FILE\_\_ refers to the file where this line is located, which would be the parent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to do this globally in `b`'s constructor due to the nature of `__FILE__` - it does not behave like a function, but is a magic constant that gets processed (and replaced with its actual value) when the file is interpreted.

You will have to do this in each child separately. This works in PHP 5:

```
class a1 extends b{ private $path = __FILE__;}
class a2 extends b{ private $path = __FILE__;}
class a3 extends b{ private $path = __FILE__;}
class a4 extends b{ private $path = __FILE__;}
class a5 extends b{ private $path = __FILE__;}
```

The only way I know to do this in the parent is using `debug_backtrace()`, and that is not a good practice.

Comment: @Pekka:You can not assign the value to the property directly, either assign in the constructor or in a method of class

Comment: @Shakti I can, tested it in PHP 5.3. If there is a PHP version where this is not possible, please tell me which one and I'll amend the information

Comment: @Shakti : No, you can do this.

Comment: it is possible in php5.2 also.

Comment: @Pekka: Agree now, but before I saw on the SO a guy have trying to this and a failed and SO expert advise him, he can not do in that way.

Comment: @Pekka: I can not revert back downvoted until you edit your answer.

Comment: @Pekka I know, but I need something in parent, not in children

Comment: @Mohammad as far as I know, that is not possible without doing a `debug_backtrace()`, and that is too expensive.